# LinkedIn Share drops url - Creating My Own Sharing Links

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am making my own share menu and I have several social shares working already. However linkedIn poses a problem because the url doesn't get included on the redirect it seems. It's the same code for the rest of the working shares so I don't know what is wrong.

JS

```
var url = window.location.href+'"';
var title = document.title;

var popup = '<div id="popup"><p id="shareHeader">Share On</p>'+
            '<p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="'+url+'>Facebook</a></p>'+
            '<p><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url="'+url+'&title='+title+'>LinkedIn</a></p>'+
            '<p><a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=GET%20800%20SAT&url="'+url+'>Twitter</a></p>'+
            '<p><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={'+url+'}">Google+</a></p>'+
            '<p><a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url='+url+'>StumbleUpon</a></p>'+
            '</div><div id="close">Close</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you close the `href` tag before attaching the URL to it.

`<p><a href= >"< https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=  >"<  '+url+'&title='+title+'>LinkedIn</a></p>`

You need to make it look like this:

```
var url = window.location.href+'"';
var title = document.title;

var popup = '<div id="popup"><p id="shareHeader">Share On</p>'+
            '<p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url+'">Facebook</a></p>'+
            '<p><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+url+'&title='+title+'">LinkedIn</a></p>'+
            '<p><a href="http://twitter.com/share?text=GET%20800%20SAT&url='+url+'">Twitter</a></p>'+
            '<p><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={'+url+'}">Google+</a></p>'+
            '<p><a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url='+url+'">StumbleUpon</a></p>'+
            '</div><div id="close">Close</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also share from your web application using this.

1. Script for posting to Facebook

   ```
   <script>
     (function (d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=Your app Id";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
   ```
2. Script for Twitter

   ```
   <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
   </script>
   ```
3. Script for posting to Linkedn

   ```
   <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
   ```
4. Script for posting to Google Plus

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>
   ```
5. Html

   ```
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
       <!-- Modal content-->
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Share on social media</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body">
               @{
                   var eventId = "WUIkEyQgjnjxsoQa";
               }
               <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://92.33.32.25/@eventId" data-width="100px" data-type="button"></div>         
               <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://92.33.32.25/@eventId" data-type="button" data-text="Share on eventry" data-via="eventry" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
               <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-expandto="right" data-annotation="none" data-height="22" data-width="55" data-href="http://92.33.32.25/WUIkEyQgjnjxsoQa"></div>
               <script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://92.33.32.25/@eventId">      </script>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

   Share